# Is the Window of WPF window container itself?

Tags: wpf, xaml

We can add **controls** on to the **window** without using additional containers, therefore

1. Is the **window** itself a container? if so what kind of the control, is it built in panel?
2. If **window** has built-in container, when Drag and Drop a **Grid** on to the window, why the XAML markup does not show this grid under the windows's panel instead it shows the **Grid** as its on the window directly ?

thanks

Comment: "add controls on to the window without using additional containers". That's wrong. There is always a single control which is the `Content` of the Window. This controls is usually a Panel, e.g. a Grid. Child controls are added to this Panel.

Comment: @Clemens: Is this Content control is a Built-in Panel? If its a Grid then it should provide Rows and Columns!

Comment: It's in the Window's XAML, which is generated when you create one in Visual Studio. By default it is a Grid without any row or column definitions.

Comment: And I would recommend against dragging controls from the VS toolbox into the window in VS designer. Either you write the XAML yourself (it is easy because there is IntelliSense), or you use Blend.

Comment: So when i add Grid by Drag and Drop from designer it creates another Grid? this second grid is what we typically add controls to?

Comment: Why don't you just take a look at the Window's XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Window` inherits from `ContentControl`, which means it has one property, `Content`.

`ContentControl` is the base class for things like buttons, labels, tooltips etc. It does not provide any layout, and you're free to choose one that fits your needs, be it a `Grid`, `DockPanel` etc... In other words, it is not a panel type.

`Panel` inherits directly from `FrameworkElement`. The class hierarchy there is this:

```
Object
  DispatcherObject
    DependencyObject
      Visual
        UIElement
          FrameworkElement
            Control
              ContentControl
                Window
                UserControl
            Panel
              Grid
              StackPanel
              DockPanel
```

As you can see, the closest common ancestor shared by `Window` and `Grid` is `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: so if i drag and drop a button to a window without a Grid what happens?

Comment: You will get a window containing one button that fills the whole window. You'll be able to place other content inside the button, but you won't be able to put anything else in the window directly.